# With octave plot, how to plot points with connection line?

Tags: plot, octave

I have data like this:

```
x = [23, 25, 28, 29, ...]
y = [25, 38, 38, 28, ...]
```

Now, I can plot the points with `plot(x, y, '.r');`

I collect above points data by a time sequence, now, I want to connect the points with a line, so that I can see which is the next point of one specific point.

Answer (score 14):

`plot()` can be used to draw points-and-lines like this:

```
plot(x, y, 'o-r');
```

This draws the points as circles, and connects them with lines, all in red.

Comment: Tested. Exactly what I want.